# Basic Approach for Bondtrading with Corda

Tags: transactions, frameworks, customization, blockchain, corda

So i'm trying to learn about how to use the Corda Framework and managed to build some sample Application from the corda template so far.(this one https://docs.corda.net/head/tut-two-party-introduction.html)

Now that it comes to a concrecte Implementation of some basics for our Target Application i'm a little stuck.

At first i'm explaining what i want to achieve and afterwards i'll explain my problems so far.

I want to build a simple Bond-Trading Application where Partys offering Bonds can trade with Partys buying them. After a Timewindow the Bond + a defined fee has to be paid back.
The Application should be bound to a walletserver to validate transactions depending on whether payments have taken place.
I want to have a website, where partys can login and see what kind of bonds are currently available and start transactions.

So after playing around a little i'm now completely confused about how to use corda properly to achieve this..

As far as i was told, offering Partys need to initially put their Offers on the Blockchain. So lets say Party A wants to sell 5000 Units with a 5% Fee, it would create a Transaction(basictransaction), with no inputstate which then is put on the ledger.
If Party B wants to buy 1000 Units of this, it needs to refer to this transaction and create a new one, which takes the basictransactions resultstate as inputstate.
So at this Point, if i understand the concept correctly, i would have 2 Outputstates. One for the actual Transaction, which holds the data for 1000 units bought, the fee, the duedate and the participating Partys.
The other one would be the updated basictransaction, containing the new amount of Units left to offer, so 4000.

First question is, is this approach okay or is this a total nonsense? I'm completely unexperienced with this and have no idea or feeling yet for good or common practices.
Another question comming to my mind is, how does Party A make it its offer accessable for other Partys? Since all transactions are only visible for the participating Partys, the basictransaction wouldnt be visible for every other Party in the Network.
My Idea was to send the hash of the transaction to my webserver, which stores it and lists all Offers on my frontend. So if Party B logs in there will be a list displayed, containing available offers. B starts a transaction which means a Request is send to A, with the nessecary data(hash of basic, amount of units etc) and A then initializes the transaction with B.
This seems quite indirectly, i have no idea if this is secure and it leads to other problems.
In my Flow i would have to differentiate between the offering and the buying Party, because the buying Party only needs to sign the transaction it is involved in, not the update of the basic-transaction, which is updated in the webserver anyways. 
I have no idea yet how to achieve this, because if i put 2 outputstates in my transactionbuilder, i apply the same signing-conditions on both, if i split it into two transactions, the inputstate will be consumed after the first one and cant be inputstate for the 2nd transaction anymore..

Ya it seems i got a lot of things wrong in this, and i really would appreciate if someone could lighten this up a little for me.
Of course i read the Docs and tutorials, but most examples are very basic and currently i'm not able to extrapolate this to my usecase.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there CardMechanic,

Just as a quick answer to start, there's a sample app that's very similar to what you've described here online that represents loan tracking and issuance, take a look at that online here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp

> question one, is this total nonsense? 
>   no not at all, this is a great start and I think you're doing a fine job so far.

Just remember that states are things you want to represent, contracts represent the different ways that those things can change (loan payments, car has new owner, etc.). You trigger transactions using flows to cause changes (issue loans, sell a car, etc.) that use the contracts to verify what happens with those things.

> Another question coming to my mind is, how does Party A make it its offer accessible for other Partys?

So when party A wants to do something involved with Party B you would specify that when executing the flow and handle the party within the flow and submit B as a party for one of the subflows.

Best of luck with your work in blockchain. Also, FYI R3 has a slack for Corda, you can join it on slack.corda.net